# why ++ or -- can't be applied directly on literals in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, operators

I am learning JavaScript, now in the operators chapter. I was wondering why `++true` is an invalid expression in JavaScript and `+true` is just fine. I guess the differences are because of the way `++` (or `--`) operator work in JavaScript. Just curious to know what happens when `++` is applied.

```
console.log(+true); // 1, fine
console.log(++true); // SyntaxError
```

Why `true` isn't implicitly converted to number and incremented as it is in the case of `+`.

When the value is stored in a variable, `++` does the expected job, but we can't use it directly on literals.

Comment: Look into "left-hand-side" and "right-hand-side" expressions; might shed some light. Long story short, what is a reasonable thing for the code `1 = 1 + 1` to do?

Comment: `true` is no variable, `+` is an [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`++` adds 1 to the value in the variable, and also assigns that incremented value back to the variable. This doesn't make sense when the parameter isn't a variable. You can't change the value of `true`. `++true` is equivalent to `true = true + 1`.

You can't use `++` on *any* literal, e.g. `console.log(++3)` is also an error, since it's equivalent to `console.log(3 = 3 + 1)`.

Note that `++` *will* convert a boolean to an integer if necessary, but it has to be in a variable:

```js
x = true;
console.log(++x);
```

Comment: Once I thought that this would really be meaningless if I can do ++1 or so. But then I thought other than implicit type conversion, +1 (or similar expressions) are also useless.

Comment: `+` converts its argument to a number. If it's already a number, it doesn't do anything, but it's useful for consistency. Just like `x.toString()` will work properly if `x` is already a string.

Answer (score 3):

Because when you use `++` or `--`, it changes the value of the variable you're operating on.

```js
var a = 1;
console.log(++a);
console.log(a);
console.log(--a);
console.log(a);
```

By doing `++true` you're implying that you're *changing the value of `true`* which would be an absolutely terrible thing to do.

Since `true` is a non-mutable value, you can't use a mutating operator on it.

Answer (score 1):

The `++` and `--` pre- and post-decrement operators implicitly modify the operand variable or property. The operand *must* be something that can appear on the left side of an assignment operator, or else it doesn't make sense to use `++` or `--`.

The same is true for C, C++, Java, and I imagine most if not all the C-heritage programming languages that include those operators.

Answer (score 0):

The `++` and `--` operator changes the value.
In your case you're trying to increment value of `boolean` or non mutable value which is not possible the way you're doing.

```
var x = 10;
console.log(++x) // Output 11
console.log(x++) // Output 12
//Or
var y = true;
console.log(y++) //Output 2
```

In second scenario output is two because `true` is equal to `1` and `false` is equal to `0`.